Install4j InstallServiceAction version line 'systemd 252 (252-18.el9)' unexpected
Install4 InstallServiceAction logs in installation.log for Red Hat 9:
ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.InstallServiceAction [ID install_example_service_linux]: version line 'systemd 252 (252-18.el9)' unexpected

[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.InstallServiceAction [ID install_example_service_linux]: systemd version 0
       systemctl daemon-reload return: 0
       Execute action successful after 1018 ms


The service installation seems to be done, the service is installed. Other 3 services are installed without any error/warning after this is thrown the first time. I don't see an functional impact but why does this appear?
Install4j version is 8.9.0

This problem is fixed since install4j 9.0. The impact of this problem is that the systemd file will use Type=simple instead of Type=exec even for newer versions of systemd (such as yours).
